# How to dynamically change the reporting to name in email body

Tags: email, email-template

I send the mail to reporting manager and i want to mention the manager in email body(sample Dear XXX,).But in my scenario manager level was changed (For example A1-B1-C1 and other one is A1-B2-C1-D).If the 2nd role "D" employee was reporting to "C" and 1st role "C" employee was reporting to "B". How to use common structure for this condition.How to change the manager name based on the role wise.

Comment: if using a VF email template, you can include a VF Component with a corresponding custom controller that would look up the relevant manager name based on however high the role hierarchy extends for the employee ID in question

Comment: i use custom html template,and i new to SF. I dont know how to use VF component and controller

Comment: For VF email templates, see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_intro.htm.  HTML email templates can't traverse the role hierarchy as there is no merge field that will do this;